# Canon EOS 1000 / Nikon + Delphi

Tags: delphi, camera

I am looking for a way to be able to control my Canon or Nikon camera from delphi,
Basically I need to find a way to receive the new image while the camera is connected with USB on the fly, i.e. detect when a new picture was taken, so I can take action in my application for example cropping the image, adjusting brightness etc etc

I look at Canon's homepage and seems they do not offer SDK for europe.

please advice, anyone ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To control a device like a camera you have two options

1) use an SDK which is supplied by the manufacturer of the device.

- [Canon SDK](http://www.didp.canon-europa.com/) Web Page
- [Nikon SDK](https://sdk.nikonimaging.com/apply/) Web Page

2) use the [Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368%28VS.85%29.aspx), from the delphi IDE you can use the Component->Import Component->`Import Type Library` option to create a wrapper to work with this library.

Answer (score 1):

I have good experience with [CamRemote](http://alkenius.no-ip.org/TCamRemote/) and integrated it in several applications

Answer (score 1):

Look also for (Delphi) TCamRemote for Canon camera. It comes with sources and many demos.